# Unity Changing the Text of an object in another script/scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Basically, I have this Text (scoreText) which is in my "Menu" scene so hence I have initiated it in GameControlMenu.cs, however, I'm trying to change its text from my other script GameControl.cs whilst I'm currently on my "Main" scene.

**GameControlMenu.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameControlMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

public static GameControlMenu instanceMenu;

public Text scoreText;

void Start()
{
    //does stuff but not important to question
}
}
```

**GameControl.cs:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
public static GameControl instance;

public int score = 5;

void Start()
{   
    GameControlMenu.instanceMenu.scoreText.text = "PREVIOUS SCORE: " + score;
}
}
```

This setup works for a couple of my other variables which I'm accessing from another file but for whatever reason this just keeps throwing me the error: **NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: This NullReferenceException tells you that some variable in your code is null. First we need to do is find which is the variable that is null. Do you manage to find that?

Comment: @dedecos the only variable I'm using in changing the text is my int "score" but that is definitely not null. I even removed that from the string and it still threw me the same error.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `GameControlMenu.instanceMenu`?

Comment: @dedecos It is simply an instance of my GameControlMenu since Unity requires that to access variables from other cs files

Comment: Can you show the code where you define a value to the variable `GameControlMenu.instanceMenu`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do `GameControlMenu.instanceMenu...` since `GameControlMenu` is in another scene as you described, and the instance isn't in the current scene.

But what you can do is to store the value somewhere first, and let the `GameControlMenu` use it when the other scene loads like so:

#### GameControlMenu.cs

```
public class GameControlMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static GameControlMenu instanceMenu;

    public static string StuffToShowOnScoreText { get; set; }

    public Text scoreText;

    void Awake()
    {
        // So that it loads the text on start
        scoreText.text = StuffToShowOnScoreText;
        // ...
    }
}
```

#### GameControl.cs

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameControl instance;

    public int score = 5;

    void Start()
    {   
        // Store the value 
        GameControlMenu.StuffToShowOnScoreText = "PREVIOUS SCORE: " + score;
    }
}
```